# Discord.py Adding role by command

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

can anyone help me! What's wrong here. Thanks!

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions( manage_roles = True )

    async def addrole( ctx, member: discord.Member = None, role: discord.Role = None, guild: discord.Guild = None ):
    guild = ctx.guild if not guild else guild
    emb = discord.Embed( title = 'Add role', colour = discord.Color.green())
    await ctx.channel.purge( limit = 1 )

    await client.add_roles( member, role )

    emb.set_author( name = guild, icon_url = guild.icon_url )
    emb.set_footer( text = 'Was added by {}'.format( ctx.author.name ), icon_url = ctx.author.avatar_url )
    emb.set_thumbnail( url = member.avatar_url )
    emb.add_field( name = 'Role added to user', value = '{}'.format( member.mention ) )
    emb.add_field( name = 'Added role is', value = '{}'.format( role ) )

    await ctx.send( embed = emb )
```

I tried to write code by myself and tried watch tutorial, but none of that codes isnt working.

Comment: You should provide the error (if any) and the actual/expected outcome. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as though you might be using some old documentation (v0.16.x) for adding the role. I'd recommend looking into more recent tutorials.

In rewrite (v1.x), the syntax for `add_roles()` has changed, and is now a method in the `discord.Member` object:

```py
@client.command()
async def addrole(ctx, member: discord.Member, role: discord.Role):
    await member.add_roles(role)
    await ctx.send(f"Successfully gave {role.name} to {member}!")
```

---

**References:**

- [f-Strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) - Python 3.6.0+
- [Migrating to rewrite](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html)
- [Rewrite docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)
- [`Member.add_roles()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.add_roles)

Answer (score 0):

I edited that and got this!

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions( manage_roles = True )

async def addrole( ctx, member: discord.Member = None, role: discord.Role = None, 
    guild: discord.Guild = None ):
    guild = ctx.guild if not guild else guild
    emb = discord.Embed( title = 'Add role', colour = discord.Color.green())
    await ctx.channel.purge( limit = 1 )

    await member.add_roles( role )

    emb.set_author( name = guild, icon_url = guild.icon_url )
    emb.set_footer( text = 'Was added by {}'.format( ctx.author.name ), icon_url = ctx.author.avatar_url )
    emb.set_thumbnail( url = member.avatar_url )
    emb.add_field( name = 'Role added to user', value = '{}'.format( member.mention ) )
    emb.add_field( name = 'Added role is', value = '{}'.format( role ) )

await ctx.send( embed = emb )
```